# How do I cancel an AsyncTask running BitmapFactory.decodeFile() and clean-up

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, bitmapfactory

In my interface, the user selects from a variable number of songs, and when a song is selected, I need to display the relevant background image.
The user needs to keep control of the interface while the images are loading, and still be able to change song.

The way I currently do this is using an AsyncTask.

I am executing it using:

```
if (LoadBG!=null&&!LoadBG.isCancelled())
LoadBG.cancel(false);

LoadBG = new loadBG();
LoadBG.execute((Object) diff.BGPath);
```

attempting to cancel the previous task if it is still running and creating it anew.

The task code does the bitmap loading:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... param) {

        String pathName = param[0].toString();
        if (!pathName.equals(gfxStore.currentBGPath)) {

            currentBGLoaded = false;
            while(overlayOpacity!=255)
                Thread.yield();
            //set current bg
            if (this.isCancelled())
                return true;
            Bitmap d;
            try
            {
            d = gfxStore.factory.decodeFile(pathName,gfxStore.opts);
            }
            catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
            {
                System.gc();
                return true;
            }
            if (this.isCancelled())
            {
                d.recycle();
                d = null;
                System.gc();
                return true;
            }
            Bitmap s;
            try
            {
            s = gfxStore.scaleImageForCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight,d );
            }
            catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
            {
                //XXX uuuugh
                System.gc();
                return true;
            }
            if (this.isCancelled())
            {
                d.recycle();
                d=null;
                s.recycle();
                s=null;
                System.gc();
                return true;
            }
            d.recycle();
            d=null;
            System.gc();
            gfxStore.currentBG = s;
            gfxStore.currentBGPath = pathName;
            wasChange = true;
        }
        else
            wasChange=false;
        return true;
    }
```

I've made quite a mess of recycling, nulling, running GC, all attempting to cancel the current task so that the newly created one will have enough memory for available for allocation,but whatever I try, I always get outofmemory exceptions when attempting to run too many too soon (about 4/5 times)

The images are 1024x768 jpg files, and ask for 1.5mb memory allocation, i use the bitmapfactory options:

```
opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    opts.inPurgeable = true;
    opts.inSampleSize = 1;
```

Absolutely -any- advice would be appreciated, I've searched to no end about recycling bitmaps, nulling, GCing, attempting to use purgeable bitmaps.

Comment: You may want to consider http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8488 as well.

Comment: I have, thanks, but that wasn't the case I believe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try to serialize the calls with a Mutex, so that only one operation (even if it is being cancelled for some reason) executes? See a very rudimentary approach below.  Obviously you could do more selective locking within the **doInBackground** method, but you get the picture.

```
static class DecodeLock extends Object {
}
static public DecodeLock lockObject = new DecodeLock();

// ...

protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... param) {
   synchronized (lockObject) {
      String pathName = param[0].toString();
          if (!pathName.equals(gfxStore.currentBGPath)) {

          //[..snip]
    }
 }
```

Comment: Wow, it seems to be working fine now without any OOM errors. Just to understand this, is this causing the current task to finish it's cancelling before the next begins to run (as it is waiting on synchronization)?

Comment: Yes, basically each AsyncTask is run on a separate thread (this is a simplification but good enough for our purposes).  When one thread hits the "synchronized" keyword, it aquires a lock on 'lockObject' until the matching brace at the end of the block.  So if another thread comes in at the same time, it will block at the "synchronized" line until the current thread is done processing (whether it processes successfully or cancels).  Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 for concurrency, I feel most people could use a refresher on its importance.