# AsyncTask run on one single thread in Android 2.3.3 (VERSION.SDK_INT = 10)

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Following the Android's document

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

Is there any way to run AsyncTask on one single thread in Android 2.3.3 ? I intended to use executeOnExecutor but it only support for version sdk > 11

Comment: well, you can manually block running another task while first is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the guide in this link [How do I cancel an AsyncTask running BitmapFactory.decodeFile() and clean-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732702/how-do-i-cancel-an-asynctask-running-bitmapfactory-decodefile-and-clean-up) . I put the synchronized to the doInBackground method and see it worked.